GLSL bouncing ball issue
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2  u_resolution;
uniform vec2  u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;

vec3 color_bg = vec3(1.0);
vec3 circle_color = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

void circle(float radius, vec2 pos, vec2 mouse, vec2 view, float speed) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color_bg, 1.0);
    float aspect_ratio = u_resolution.x / u_resolution.y;
    pos.x += u_time * speed;
    float circle_radius = sqrt(pow((view.x * aspect_ratio - pos.x * aspect_ratio), 2.0) + pow((view.y - pos.y), 2.0));   
    if(pos.x + radius >= 1.0 || pos.x - radius <= 0.0) {
        //  Background orange color change for debugging
        gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0.9686, 0.5529, 0.298), 1.0);
        speed = -speed;
    }
    if(circle_radius <= radius) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(circle_color, 1.0);
    }
}

void main() {
    vec2 normalized_view = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;
    vec2 normalized_mouse = u_mouse.xy/u_resolution;
    vec2 circle_position = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
    float speed = 0.2;
    circle(0.03, circle_position, normalized_mouse, normalized_view, speed);
}

Hi everyone,
I am new(few days) to GLSL or "Graphic Programming" for that matter. Despite asking the question to ChatGPT, neither me nor ChatGPT could solve it, so, the problem is that for some reason the circle does not bounce upon colliding against the borders. I do not expect you to write me the code, just detailed explanation would be highly appreciated. I am guessing it has something to do with the call stack but still..
Hardware: MacBook M1 Pro

A shader has no state, so pos.x += u_time * speed together with speed = -speed will not help you implement a bounce here.
I see two possible solutions.

Use a triangle wave function to calculate pos.x given u_time. Example:
pos.x = abs(fract(u_time * speed) - 0.5);
Calculate pos.x in application code, outside of the shader (where you do have state), and pass it into the shader through a uniform, just like you do with u_time.


Do I need to use Vertex Shader to do it? or it can be achieved within a single frag. file. I have restricted myself to use only the Fragment Shader for self-teaching purposes, once I get completely comfortable with Fragment Shader, I will move on to OpenGL. I mean the second solution.

There must be a program that sets up the shader, gives it a viewport, passes in parameters (uniforms) and triggers the shader to render each frame. That program runs on the CPU, as opposed to the shaders, which run on the GPU. It can be written in any programming language, for example JavaScript or C#. Solution 2 is about that part of the code.
